# Should se.fit = TRUE in predict.merMod() be used, now that it is functional again?

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, prediction, standard-error

I know the functionality of se.fit was removed from the predict() function in lme4 for mixed effects models a long time ago (due to not properly accounting for variations due to the random effects [and these problems](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/147)). I'm not sure when the functionality was removed, but it looks like it has been added back in recent months. I was just wondering if this was intentional.

Should it be used? I can't find any documentation on recent changes, and I am curious about how the function now computes standard errors for linear mixed-effects models.

Comment: Welcome to this site. I see there's a vote to close, which might be justified given that the change you mentioned is already 6-7 years old (from the Git log, AFAICT), and that this post appears ambiguous as to its purpose, i.e., whether it's only concerned with R's `lme4`, however great this package is, or whether you are concerned with computing standard errors in the case of linear mixed-effect models. If the latter, please update your question.

Comment: Thanks @chl. I edited my question (hopefully) for clarity. I'm aware that the initial removal of the functionality of se.fit happened many years ago, but since it has been renewed very recently, I was hoping to find out what has changed and if it now more adequately accounts for those variations arising due to the random effects.

Comment: Would you not find better answers on the R-sig-mixed-models mailing list?

Comment: Maybe - thanks for the suggestion!